# Ckeditor security concerns in laravel

Tags: security, laravel-5, ckeditor

I want to let my users post articles on my website but i have serious concerns about ckeditor security.

**What i want to ask is:**

1. Can users upload any kind of codes that can put my site at risk through ckeditor?
2. Is there any way to limit users of those kind of actions?

**About my application:**

I'm using laravel 5.6 and ckeditor last version.

*Please share your thoughts and experiences.*

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor is not insecure on purpose. No sense in developing an insecure product (except for educational purposes). It doesn't allow uploading executable content (as a feature). However, it does have a history of publicly exploited vulnerabilities, mostly due to it's handling of wide variety of user input that will be stored in **user accessible locations/paths**.

Nonetheless, you can still mitigate it's risks substantially if you simply restrict the paths which allow web app execution (php, asp, etc...).

PHP example:

Create an `.htaccess` file in the dir where ckeditor places it's user generated/uploaded data. Inside that file place the following:

```
php_flag engine off
```

There are additional methods to achieve this, which depend on your specific environment. But the main idea remains - **block execution abilities in the target dir for user content/uploads, and watch out for security updates for all your components.**

One last note - the best practice to avoid users uploading executable content would be to store in a non-web-exposed location. I would even advise outside of the web served root dir. This also would help to prevent a big portion of **path traversal** vulnerabilities. But specifically for CKEditor type of plugin it makes the solution much more complicated, since that content needs to be accessed by web users (by design!).